# Convert to lambda expression?

Tags: python, lambda

Is it possible to convert the following into a lambda expression?

```
def default(o):
    if isinstance(o, (datetime.date, datetime.datetime)):
        return o.isoformat()

json.dumps(raw, default=default)
```

Something like:

```
json.dumps(raw, default=lambda o: o.isoformat() if isinstance(o, (datetime.date, datetime.datetime))...? )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be able to with:

```
default = lambda o: o.isoformat() if isinstance(
    o, (datetime.date, datetime.datetime)) else o.__dict__
```

You can use `None` as well for your return, but see what happens when you do that if you were to include a custom object that `JSONEncoder` doesn't pick up on:

```
default = lambda o: o.isoformat() if isinstance(
    o, (datetime.date, datetime.datetime)) else None


class A:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x


a = A(10)
d = {'date': datetime.datetime.now(), 'myobject': a}
f = json.dumps(z, default=default)

>>> json.loads(f)
{'date': '2020-08-13T22:35:46.872594', 'myobject': None}
```

Same thing but with `o.__dict__`:

```
>>> json.loads(f)
{'date': '2020-08-13T22:36:22.512864', 'myobject': {'x': 10}}
```

Although with a custom object ideally you should have `__repr__` set up well and then you can even recreate your object.

Comment: why `o.__dict__` instead of `None` or `o` or something else?

Comment: I just think it is a better habit/usage than `None` because say you have a dict with a custom object in there as well. Try encoding then decoding that - you will get `None` for the custom object. Returning `o.__dict__` can have issues though, read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768895/how-to-make-a-class-json-serializable) for more info.

Comment: @Algebra8 my inclination would be to throw an error, and explicitly deal with each possible type you may have.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga you definitely could do that but then you would have to run the encoding again every time you run into that error, instead of just doing it in one shot. Also, this is not a hack; look into overriding `JSONEncoder`.

Answer (score 1):

You need an `else` to finish the conditional expression. Since a function returns `None` by default if it doesn't execute an explicit `return` statement, that's what your `else` should be.

```
json.dumps(raw, default=lambda o: o.isoformat() if isinstance(o, (datetime.date, datetime.datetime)) else None)
```

Comment: thanks, what would happen if I tried to return `o` itself instead of None if it misses?

Comment: That would probably be better. But you should do that in your `default()` function as well.

Answer (score 1):

Just as you described, you can also add else statement there to handle output that returns false from the if check (splitted lines to get some readability, python might like more the oneliner).

```
json.dumps(raw, default=lambda o: o.isoformat() 
                                  if isinstance(o, (datetime.date, datetime.datetime)) 
                                  else None)
```